# Debugging en Visual Studio - Punto de interrupción no se activará actualmente

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual

Cuando coloco un punto de interrupción, me aparece sobre el en tiempo de ejecución el mensaje.

"El punto de interrupcion no se activara actualmente. breakpoint set but not yet bound"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4):

Si tienes varios proyectos abiertos, asegúrate que tu proyecto por defecto es el esperado ([enlace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y.aspx)).

Además, recuerda que para que los breakpoints funcionen debes ejecutar el proyecto en modo debug, no en modo release

Comment: Algo que me pasa mucho es que mi proyecto no se compila correctamente y sigue usando una versión anterior (alguna configuración mía quizás o algo más), cuando me pasa eso uso `rebuild`.

Answer (score 1):

Esto se suele solucionar dando a "Limpiar solución" y luego a "Recompilar solución". En caso de que no funcionase tras hacer esas dos operaciones (cosa rara), entra en la carpeta bin\Debug del proyecto y borra el archivo .pdb para que se regenere de nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Señalas Proyecto -> Propiedades del proyecto. En la sección de Compilación, desactivar la opción de "Optimizar código". Entonces ya funcionarán los puntos de interrupción.

Answer (score 0):

En visual Studio 2017, si estás depurando y no se te activan los breakpoints, abre la ventana módulos desde Menú Principal->Depurar->Ventanas->Módulos, en la columna "Estados de símbolos" verás que no se han generado símbolos para ese ensamblado.
Para solucionarlo, detén la ejecución y abre la venta de propiedades del proyecto
Menú Principal->Proyecto->Propiedades de "Nombre de tu proyecto".
Ve a la pestaña "Compilación" y en el apartado de abajo "Salida" pulsa en el botón "Avanzadas..."
Se abre la ventana "Configuración avanzada de compilación", en el apartado Salida en el desplegable "Información de depuración" selecciona "Completa".
Acepta el cambio y vuelve a ejecutar. Verás que ya se generan y cargan los símbolos y se activan todos los breakpoints que tengas en el código.